# AssetCompress for CakePHP 1.3

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-1.3, minify, assets

I'm using [AssetCompress](https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress) v0.5 from the 1.3 branch and the dynamic built is not working. I've done the following so far:

1. Downloaded and copied the `asset_compress` folder into my `app/plugins` folder
2. Copied the `config.ini` and renamed it to `app/config/asset_compress.ini`
3. Created 2 CSS and JS bundles named `public` and `logged` (so 4 in total)
4. Added `AssetCompress.AssetCompress` in my `$helpers` array in my `AppController`
5. Changed my `default.ctp` layout file to: `echo $this->AssetCompress->css('public'); echo $this->AssetCompress->css('logged');` (same for `->script()`)

The output error is:

> Error: The requested address '/asset_compress/assets/get/public.css' was not found on this server.

What am I missing?

Comment: I did the same yesterday in 1.3 - and it worked beautifully.
what does your config file currently state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.
It was because I was using the CssMin filter and I did not download it and put it into the vendor folder. As the plugin seems to be turning the debug level to 0, I did not see the error, until I put a `Configure::write('debug', 2);` into the `beforeFilter()`.